# Read file after writing in same script (Ruby the Hard Way ex16)

Tags: ruby

Here is my code:

```
filename = ARGV.first

puts "We're gong to erase #{filename}"
puts "If you don't want that, hit CTRL-C (^C)."
puts "If you do want that, hit RETURN."

$stdin.gets

puts "Opening the file..."
target = open(filename, 'w')

puts "Truncating the file. Goodbye!"
target.truncate(0)

puts "Now I'm going to ask you for three lines."

print "line 1: "
line1 = $stdin.gets.chomp
print "line 2: "
line2 = $stdin.gets.chomp
print "line 3: "
line3 = $stdin.gets.chomp

puts "I'm going to write these to the file."

target.write(line1)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line2)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line3)
target.write("\n")


print target.read
puts "And finally, we close it."


target.close
```

I'm trying to get it to write and then read.  It works if I do `target.close` and then `target = open(filename)` again at the bottom of the script.  Is there another way?

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14100937/cannot-read-file-after-writing-to-it) post about python explaining you need to close a file after writing to it.  Does this same thing apply to Ruby?  Do I need to use flush?

Also should I be using parentheses after read and close?  The example does not.

Comment: This is less a language issue and more a file system / operating system issue. What operating system are you on?  Windows has mandatory locking which means if you have a file open you can't open it again until it's closed.  Unix (including Mac) will let you scribble on files as much as you like.

Comment: This "Ruby the hard way" code does not look like Ruby at all, it looks like a line by line literal translation from Python.

Comment: "Learn Ruby The Hard Way" appears to be a direct translation of ["Learn Python The Hard Way"](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex16.html).  @steenslag is right, it's not very good Ruby.  I would avoid it.  I'd recommend using Learn Python The Hard Way to learn programming techniques (file manipulation techniques are universal) and use something else to learn Ruby like [the original Pickaxe](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/). I do *not* recommend [the updated Programming Ruby for 2.0](http://www.amazon.com/gp/review/RBK4K4T9YDA9L/ref=cm_cr_pr_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=1937785491).

Comment: Oh man!! You mean I wasted all these hours for nothing?  So what else is good besides pickaxe?  I was trying to learn a good amount of Ruby before going into rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways to approach this.  You can, as you've done, open the file for writing, write to it, close the file, and reopen it for reading.  This is fine.  Closing the file will flush it to disk and reopening it will put you back at the beginning of the file.

Alternatively you can open a file for both reading and writing and manually move around within the file, like a cursor in an editor.  The options to do this are defined in [IO.new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/IO.html#method-c-new).

The problem with your code is this.

```
target.write("\n")

print target.read
```

At this point you've been writing to the file.  The `target` file pointer is pointing at the end of the file, like a cursor in an editor.  When you `target.read` it's going to read the end of the file, so you get nothing.  You'd have to go back to the beginning of the file first with [rewind](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/IO.html#method-i-rewind).

```
target.write("\n")
target.rewind
print target.read
```

You'll also have to open the file for reading and writing.  `w+` can do that, and truncate the file for you.

```
puts "Opening the file..."
target = File.open(filename, 'w+')
```

This is an advanced technique most often useful for when you want to hold a lock on a file during the whole reading and writing process to make sure nobody else can work on the file while you are.  Generally you do this when you're reading and then writing.  For example, if you had a counter in a file you want to read and then increment and make sure nobody can write between.

```
def read_and_update_counter
  value = 0

  # Open for reading and writing, create the file if it doesn't exist
  File.open("counter", File::RDWR|File::CREAT, 0644) {|f|
    # Get an exclusive lock to prevent anyone else from using the
    # file while we're updating it (as long as they also try to flock)
    f.flock(File::LOCK_EX)

    # read the value
    value = f.read.to_i

    # go back to the beginning of the file
    f.rewind

    # Increment and write the new value
    f.write("#{value + 1}\n")

    # Flush the changes to the file out of the in-memory IO cache
    # and to disk.
    f.flush

    # Get rid of any other garbage that might be at the end of the file
    f.truncate(f.pos)
  }
  # File.open automatically closes the file for us    

  return value
end

3.times { puts read_and_update_counter }
```

Comment: OP did not write the code, it's a tutorial (and not a very good one IMHO).

Comment: Any tutorials you prefer?

Comment: @user4584963 The [original Programming Ruby](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/). Avoid Programming Ruby 2.0, totally different book.